# Is there any straightforward I2C device tester?

Tags: arduino, i2c, test-equipment

I work with a few I2C sensors such the MAX30102. At this point, the only way to test my sensors is building a minimum Arduino setup and get the I2C sensor's reading.

I am using a low-cost device like below to test my electronic parts. It is working very well for me:

[image]

The surprising convenience of the tester gave me the idea of looking for an I2C device tester.

Is there any straightforward I2C device tester? Is there any well-known, generalized Arduino sketch that people use for testing I2C devices?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to find out when you "test" it?

Comment: I recommend a bus pirate, if you can find one in stock.

Comment: @DKNguyen, I just want to read a MAX30102 or humidity tester reading without the need for setting up an  Arduino sketch.

Comment: Ehhh that's probably not happening.

Comment: You can buy one Arduino and dedicate it to that task. Build different chip sockets for different types of chips you want to test. You can have a display or then just make it as an I2C interface basically it will be a PC program doing the logical part.

Comment: ***I2C Debug for RealTerm*** - Jim Hamblen, 2011mar14
https://os.mbed.com/users/4180_1/notebook/i2c-debug-for-realterm/

Comment: Since I didn't see it mentioned, here's the OG Arduino sketch for scanning a bus to find chips: https://github.com/todbot/arduino-i2c-scanner/blob/master/I2CScanner/I2CScanner.ino

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, and there can't be.

I2C is a de facto standard, but there are no standard interfaces. There's no I2C equivalent of SCPI or anything, so you can't know what messages to send to the device to get it to do anything--what one device might interpret as "initialize the device", another one might read as "erase all data".

Comment: so you need a device with selector: ADS1115, ADS7828, ADXL345, BMP180 ... and [gazillion](https://i2cdevices.org/devices) other options?

Comment: @aaaaasaysreinstateMonica Basically. You could probably find groups of devices that have sufficiently similar interfaces and treat them together, or you could just let the user send arbitrary I2C messages, but because there's no SCPI-like standard interface, you can't really do better than that. I suppose you could discover a device's address by trying to read from it (which *shouldn't* have any side-effects), but then you have no guarantee that the address you try to read actually exists, so who knows.

Answer (score 6):

The best you will do is an I2C to USB adapter, converter, sniffer, debugger, or any other number of terms and PC software made for it (or an API if you want to write your own application code).

In a way, it's pretty much what you are doing with your Arduino, but you can do it with the PC which makes it easier and faster.

And it will require the component to be on its own board with the necessary circuitry to run it.

Comment: This is a nice technique and I am learning about it as we speak. Thank you for help. I think the answer to my question is that there can't be such thing and I should not try to find any off the shelf product.

Answer (score 3):

As others have pointed out, such a beast doesn't really exist, because of the nature of I2C and how it works. I2C is a hardware standard for getting bytes over a wire, with some provision for addressing and so on, but on top of that each specific device needs its own set of messages depending on what its function is, and this must differ from device to device. An I2C EEPROM must be communicated with differently from a temp sensor or an ADC.

Others have recommended I2C bus sniffers and so on. An alternative to that which I think is more general purpose is a small PC based logic analyser such as [this one](https://eur.saleae.com/products/saleae-logic-8). (Actually this company used to do a 4 channel one which was a lot cheaper - around 100€ - but it doesn't seem to exist anymore - shame.)

One of these will allow you to capture data from number of types of interface, not limited to I2C, and even allow you to write your own decoder if you find yourself dealing with an interface which is not supported. (I have found this absolutely invaluable in the past.) A bit more to shell out than a cheap sniffer, but well worth the extra IMO, if you intend to be doing embedded development for any amount of time.

EDIT : you can still find the Logic 4 if you search. Not sure why it isn't on their site.

Comment: Or *any number* of 'compatible' logic analysers from a certain country.  If you're on a shoestring budget, buy a £10/$10/10EUR '48mhz logic analyser' from your favourite, erm, unlicensed import site (a.k.a online auction), spin up [pulseview](https://sigrok.org/wiki/PulseView), and forget guesswork.  Ofc whatever logic analyser you have you still need something to interact with the device, which many 'sniffers' can actually do.

Comment: I would see nothing impractical about a small handheld device which would allow a user to configure a device address, a small number of command bytes, and a number of bytes to read back, and which would send out {stop} {start} {write address} {cmd bytes} {restart} {read address} and then read the specified number of bytes.  The numerical values and the numbers of bytes to send/receive would be different for different devices, but otherwise the same sequence of operations would be applicable for most devices.

Comment: @2e0byo interesting, didn't know about pulseview. I wonder how easy it is to write your own decoder. I have a particular affection for that feature, as a few years ago I had to do a long project using a protocol I'd never heard of called XY100 (for continuously driving motors) and I was able to write one over a weekend that saved me a TON of time later. Having the decoded motor drive displayed with other decoded data was an A++ debugging tool for a low cost. The suppliers of that particular product were pretty helpful as well. But if cash is very tight that's an interesting alternative.

Comment: @supercat that's true. Such a thing could be very handy as well, and maybe it exists. But in many cases I suspect that for the time you will spend putting command bytes in and seeing what you get out - you might as well put an analyser on it and just write a driver, which is what you will likely end up doing anyway.

Comment: @danmcb pulseview (sigrok) has many decoders built in, and they're not that hard to add.  It's a seriously good bit of software.

Answer (score 2):

The best you can really do is to start an I2C transaction and await an acknowledge, then abort the transaction.  You'd need to scan through the 128 possible addresses and see which, if any, respond.

You'd do an I2C start condition, then while generating clock pulses send the 7 bits of address plus a 1 (indicates a read), then release the data line.  If you generate another clock cycle the data line will go low to indicate the device acknowledged, or stay high if it didn't.  Then do a stop condition to abort the transaction.

It doesn't give you much, but tells you which devices are responding on the bus.  From that you can tell if they are the devices you're expecting.  It might show up problems with the I2C side interface (SDA/SCL pin failure, lack of power, missing pullup resistors), but won't test any device-specific features.  You could expand it to test common parts based on the detected addresses, but a lot of addresses are used by multiple devices so it's not a robust way to determine what is connected.

Comment: You are correct, it does not tell much, but even that case might be too optimistic. Some I2C devices simply don't acknowledge a read operation if they have nothing to send. These chips require that a register index is written first, and the read operation must continue with a restart, so that there is no stop between register index write and register data read.

Answer (score 2):

There are low-cost tools designed to help with I2C but they don't do as much as you want.

- The [BusPirate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bus_Pirate) by Dangerous Prototypes has [I2C support](http://dangerousprototypes.com/blog/bus-pirate-manual/i2c-guide/)

  > The Bus Pirate was designed for debugging, prototyping, and analysing "new or unknown chips".[1] Using a Bus Pirate, a developer can use a serial terminal to interface with a device, via such hardware protocols as SPI, I2C and 1-Wire.
- The [I2CDriver](https://i2cdriver.com/) by ExCamera is (obviously) for I2C.

  > I²CDriver is an easy-to-use, open source tool for controlling I²C devices over USB. It works with Windows, Mac, and Linux, and has a built-in color screen that shows a live "dashboard" of all the I²C activity.

I haven't got any relevant experience with these.  I can't say whether they offer much above what you'd get from any microcontroller development board.

But you'll certainly need to read and understand the data sheet of any I2C device to use these tools on them.